# How to understand the svn merge?

Tags: svn, merge

I modified the test.txt in branch, and have six committed revisions, they are 1, 2,3,4,5 and 6.

Now, I want to merge those modifications from branch to trunk, I use the below command:

```
$cd trunk-working_copy
$svn merge -r 2:6 http://XXX/branch/test.txt@1,
```

How to understand this command, does the below is right?

```
r2 diff with r1 ,then apply
r3 diff with r1 ,then apply
r4 diff with r1 ,then apply
r5 diff with r1 ,then apply
r6 diff with r1 ,then apply
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is merging changes from versions 2 to 6 of *branch* to *trunk*.

If you then do `svn st` in `trunk-working_copy`, you will notice the files that have been modified. You will then need to do a `svn commit` for the changes to actually appear in the trunk.

Basic merging in svn is explained in detail [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know it merge all of changes, but what is the meaning of "all of changes".Actually, in these revisions, each file has a final revsion, so it just merge the final revision to working copy for each file, so the "all of changes" doesnot mean all of revisions about one file, it mean different files ,right?

Comment: I think `svn` only stores changes for files in each revision. So, it will merge r2-r1, and r3-r2 and so on. So `yes` it will merge `all` changes for `all` files.

Comment: Actually,it has the same result if the svn just only merge r1-r6, as you mean, the svn maybe donnot know that, it will diff each revision, right?

Comment: @abner: You are right, it will have the same result. I can't say for sure what svn does then.

Answer (score 1):

since i cannot put this as a comment

"

```
The Key Concepts Behind Branching
```

You should remember two important lessons from this section. First, Subversion has no internal concept of a branch—it knows only how to make copies. When you copy a directory, the resultant directory is only a “branch” because you attach that meaning to it. You may think of the directory differently, or treat it differently, but to Subversion it's just an ordinary directory that happens to carry some extra historical information.

Second, because of this copy mechanism, Subversion's branches exist as normal filesystem directories in the repository. This is different from other version control systems, where branches are typically defined by adding extra-dimensional “labels” to collections of files. The location of your branch directory doesn't matter to Subversion. Most teams follow a convention of putting all branches into a /branches directory, but you're free to invent any policy you wish.

"

Comment: Thanks, I understand it,my question is how that command work? The file text.txt have six committed revision, actually, the revision 6 is the final one, so I think it just only merge the revison 6 to the working copy, right?